# C++ class member function error/exception handling during execution

Tags: c++, exception, assert

I have an assignment that to create a C++ Tokenizer class with one public method
vector  *GetTokens ( void );

The function takes a string in via stdin, tokenizes the string, and returns a vector pointer of the tokens either of size ()=1 or 2. The function needs to throw errors when: there are 0 tokens, more than 2 tokens, when the first token is not a String, or when the first token is not a String and the second is not an Integer.

```
Code that calls my function from professor:
//////////////////////
For (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
  Tokenizer tok;
  Vector<string> *test = tok.GetTokens ();

  If (test->size ()==1)  {
    cout << "Yay" << endl;
  } else {
    cout  << "Boo" << endl;
  }
///////////////
```

I have been able to successfully complete this program for proper tokenization. I am also to print out the errors via if...then statements. However, during my errors, the cout  << "Yay" or "Boo" still prints out. I need to instead not have this text print out while still allowing the for loop/calling function continue execution.

Is there a way, to use exceptions or errors with asserts in my GetTokens () method to essentially stop execution, print my error text, pass control back to the calling function without printing out any additional text and progress to the next loop cycle?
::::EDIT::::

```
My Tokenizer.cpp
///////////////////


'//Constructor
Tokenizer::Tokenizer( void ) { }

//This includes my tokenization with my error/exception handling
vector<string> * Tokenizer::GetTokens() {
string strIN;
cout << "> ";
getline(cin, strIN);

vector<string> *tokens = atokenizer(strIN);

//So with one of my constraints, I need to print an error for 0 tokens
try{
    if(tokens->size()!=0) {
        return tokens;
    } else {
        throw tokens;
    }
}
catch(vector<string> *error) {
    cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
    return error;
}
}

//This is my tokenization function which parses by whitespace
vector<string> *Tokenizer::atokenizer(string strIN) {
vector<string> *tokens = new vector<string>();

string token="";
int c=0;
bool whiteSpace=true;

//Iterates thru all chars and tokenizes by " "
for(int i=0; i<strIN.size(); i++) {
    //Checks if char==1-0,a-z,etc. or is space=" "
    if((strIN[i]>=33) && (strIN[i]<=126)) {
        //If char, appends to token
        token+=strIN[i];
        whiteSpace=false;
    }
    else if((strIN[i]==32) && (whiteSpace==false)) {
        //If space, adds token to tokens
        tokens->push_back(token);
        token="";
        c++;
        whiteSpace=true;
    }
}

//Adds final token
if(token!="") {
    tokens->push_back(token);
}

return tokens;
}'
//////////////////
```

Comment: This is where exceptions come into play, read up on them and test what happens when you `throw` something in `GetTokens`. BTW if your `GetTokens` isn't absolutely huge, then pasting it here would probably help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: There's not much point to throwing something and immediately catching it in the same function.  Typically you throw to get out of your function context and let some calling function handle it.

Comment: So I went ahead and added my Tokenizer.cpp class. Mind you, I have redone this code 15 times trying to get errors/ exceptions to work. So I rewrote it again to try and have an execution cease in my professors calling function when an input of an empty string (or 0 tokens) occurs. I get an error, but it breaks the for loop and exits my professors code. I need to have the error or exception and (I'm not really sure how to say this) but automatically start back at the point before the error occurred?

Comment: So I am C programmer and I have most of my experience in Embedded Systems. I am doing this C++ for a class. If I want to create a class that will handle inputs and situations outside of the normal scope, but will not stop exectuion, would that be error handling or exception handling?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a different way to solve my question. I couldn't get any of the error handling or exceptions to work. Instead, I just went back to using If...then...else statements to do error checking with cout and then I created functions to control the printout.

```
void coutOff() {
    cout.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)
}

void coutOn() {
    cout.clear();
}
```